# How to use biometrics prior to Android P

Tags: java, android, biometrics

I have been told that I should come to ask about how to reference the BiometricPrompt api prior to the release of Android P. I would like help on how to reference the biometrics api.I have made no progress on how to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible.

[The documentation for the biometrics package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/package-summary) shows that it was added in API level 28. The normal way to access APIs that are added in newer versions of Android is to use the Support Library, but the biometrics package is not (yet) in the Support Library.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a sample project from Android Studio that shows how to use it.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the backport currently available as alpha:

```
 implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha03'
```

Answer (score 0):

Biometrics in Android began with API level 23 and the FingerprintManager.

In API 28 this was deprecated and the BiometricPrompt is currently being used.

Although deprecated the FingerprintManager is still usable and should be used when developing an application that will reach devices that are biometric capable and prior to API 28.

see. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager